# How do I push a value only once into firebase database (firebase-admin)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push messages ids into ip "list" without pushing the same id twice,
I have tried many things but ut dosn't work how do I check if keys exist?

```
let ipsLikes = (ip,msgId) => {
  ip = ip.replace(/\./g, "dot");
  let msgD;
  let ref = db.ref(`ipslikes/${ip}`);
  ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    msgD = snapshot.val();
    if (msgD !== null) {
      if (Object.values(msgD).map((x, index) => Object.keys(x)[index]).includes(msgD)) {//Object.valuse(msgD).indexOf(msgId) > -1
        console.log("New ID");
        ref.push(msgId);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("New IP");
      ref.push(msgId);
    }
  });
}
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',55);
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',54);
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',55);
ipsLikes('11.11.11.11',55);
ipsLikes('11.11.11.11',52);
```

On the first run it's give this output it doesn't even go to the New ID line:

```
New IP
New IP
New IP
New IP
New IP
```

How do I tell it to check if a key exist and then if value?
On the second run without deleting the database it's not rewrite the IDs which is a good but not enough.

[image]

More attempts:

```
let ipsLikes = (ip,msgId) => {
  ip = ip.replace(/\./g, "dot");
  let idsArr = [];
  let ref = db.ref(`ipslikes/${ip}`);
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        idsArr.push(child.val());
      });
      console.log(idsArr+"|"+msgId);
      if (!idsArr.includes(msgId)) {
        console.log("New ID");
        ref.push(msgId);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Midlle");
      ref.push(msgId);
    }
  });
}
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',55);
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',54);
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',55);
ipsLikes('11.11.11.11',55);
ipsLikes('11.11.11.11',52);
```

returns:

```
Midlle
Midlle
Midlle
55|55
55|54
New ID
55|55
55,55,54|55
55,55,54|54
55,55,54|55
55,55,54,55,54,55|55
55,55,54,55,54,55|54
55,55,54,55,54,55|55
55,55,54,55,54,55,55,54,55,54|55
55,55,54,55,54,55,55,54,55,54|54
55,55,54,55,54,55,55,54,55,54|55
Midlle
Midlle
55|55
55|52
New ID
55,55,52|55
55,55,52|52
55,55,52,55,52,52|55
55,55,52,55,52,52|52
```

and writes:

[image]

```
let ipsLikes = (ip,msgId) => {
  ip = ip.replace(/\./g, "dot");
  let idsArr = [];
  let ref = db.ref(`ipslikes/${ip}`);
  ref.once("value").then( function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
      idsArr.push(child.val());
    });
    console.log(idsArr + "|" + msgId);
    if (!idsArr.includes(msgId)) {
      console.log("New ID");
      ref.push(msgId);
    }
  });
}
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',55);
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',54);
ipsLikes('88.88.88.88',55);
ipsLikes('11.11.11.11',55);
ipsLikes('11.11.11.11',52);
```

Output:

```
|55
New ID
|54
New ID
|55
New ID
|52
New ID
|55
New ID
```

Write data like the first image

On second run without deleting the database:

It outputs:

```
55,54,55|55
55,54,55|54
55,54,55|55
52,55|52
52,55|55
```

Without writing new data...

I tried the same but with on instead of once and then,
It writes:

[image]

With the output:

```
|55
New ID
|54
New ID
|55
New ID
55|55
55|54
New ID
55|55
55,55,54|55
55,55,54|54
55,55,54|55
55,55,54,55,54,55|55
55,55,54,55,54,55|54
55,55,54,55,54,55|55
55,55,54,55,54,55,55,54,55,54|55
55,55,54,55,54,55,55,54,55,54|54
55,55,54,55,54,55,55,54,55,54|55
|55
New ID
|52
New ID
55|55
55|52
New ID
55,55,52|55
55,55,52|52
55,55,52,55,52,52|55
55,55,52,55,52,52|52
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (Object.values(msgD).map((x, index) => Object.keys(x)[index]).includes(msgD))
```

doesn't check for presence of `msgId`.

`Object.value(msgD)` should return an array of all values currently present, eg, `[54,55]` and then `.includes(msgId)` can check if it is present in that array.

Comment: Ah shoot, I missed out a large detail. Does `Object.values(msgD).includes(msgId)` work?

Comment: It should be with a ```!``` before because it needs to check if it is not exists and then push new ID but the problem is that I've tried so many things on the if above ```if (msgD !== null) {``` but nothing seemed to work it's always go to the new IP section I need to now a better check for if the ref exist...

Comment: ```ref.once('value').then( function(snapshot) {```
with
```if (msgD == ip ) {```
and
```if (!Object.values(msgD).map((x, index) => Object.keys(x)[index]).includes(msgId)) {```
registers all IDs with the output of 5 ```New IP```
while
the same ```once```...```value```
with
```msgD = snapshot.key;```
```if (snapshot.key == ip && msgD !== null) {```
```if (!Object.values(snapshot.key).map((x, index) => Object.keys(x)[index]).includes(msgId)) {```
register all IDs with the output of ```New ID```